# Hibernate JPA model class generation in Maven project

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, maven, jpa

In my pom.xml, I added this dependency:

```
<dependency>
                        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                        <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
                        <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
                <!-- Annotation processor that raising compilation errors whenever constraint
                annotations are incorrectly used. -->
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                        <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
                        <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
```

When I compile and install the project by executing "mvn clean install" at terminal, the model classes are generated in this directory:

```
target/generated-sources/annotations/com/myproject/ne/model/
```

Then if I import this Maven project from Eclipse, it works all fine without complaining the model classes automatically generated.

However, if I don't execute "mvn clean install" at a terminal to generate the model classes and directly import the clean project, Eclipse doesn't generate the model classes, and therefore generates compilation errors.

What's needed to use the hibernate-jpamodelgen to automatically when a clean maven project is imported and compiled?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by enabling it with annotation processing.

In eclipse right click on project --> properties --> Java Compiler --> Annotation Processing --> Factory Path enable it.
Now populate the .factorypath file at the root of your project with the following contents:

```
<factorypath>
    <factorypathentry kind="PLUGIN" id="org.eclipse.jst.ws.annotations.core" enabled="true" runInBatchMode="false"/>
    <factorypathentry kind="VARJAR" id="M2_REPO/org/hibernate/hibernate-jpamodelgen/1.0.0.Final/hibernate-jpamodelgen-1.0.0.Final.jar" enabled="true" runInBatchMode="false"/>
    <factorypathentry kind="VARJAR" id="M2_REPO/org/hibernate/javax/persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api/1.0.0.Final/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.jar" enabled="true" runInBatchMode="false"/>
</factorypath>
```

Refresh the project in Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Follow @Tanvi B answer, and 1 more step:
**project --> properties --> Java Compiler --> Annotation Processing:**
**Enable project specific settings** (check all). And at **Generated source directory**, you have to define `target/generated-sources`